# Spring Transaction with Scala

Tags: spring, scala, transactional, spring-transactions

I've tried to use some beans programmed in scala in my Spring (v 3.1) web application and have encountered strange problems when it comes to transactions.

I've setup a small but complete Spring application in Roo to show my problem. To be honest, I don't have a clue why it is not working...

```
project --topLevelPackage com.app
jpa setup --provider ECLIPSELINK --database DERBY_EMBEDDED
entity jpa --class com.app.MyEntity
field string --fieldName title
```

Then I created the interfaces in java

```
package com.app;
public interface IScalaMainClass {
 void doSomething();
}

package com.app;
public interface IScala1 {
 void someMethod();
}

package com.app;
public interface IScala2 {
 void someMethod();
}
```

The implementations are created in Scala where Scala1 persists MyEntity and Scala2 makes a DELETE query:

```
package com.app

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

@Repository class ScalaMainClass extends com.app.IScalaMainClass {
 @Autowired var bean1: IScala1 = null
 @Autowired var bean2: IScala2 = null

 @Transactional def doSomething() = {
  bean1.someMethod()
  bean2.someMethod()
 }
}


package com.app

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import javax.persistence.{EntityManager, PersistenceContext}

@Repository class Scala1 extends com.app.IScala1 {
 @PersistenceContext var em: EntityManager = null

 def someMethod = {
  val e = new MyEntity
  em persist e
 }
}


package com.app

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import javax.persistence.{EntityManager, PersistenceContext}

@Repository class Scala2 extends com.app.IScala2 {
 @PersistenceContext var em: EntityManager = null

 @Transactional def someMethod = {
  val q = em createQuery "DELETE FROM MyEntity"
  q executeUpdate
 }
```

}

Finally the test in Java is created which executes the IScalaMainClass:

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;

import com.app.IScalaMainClass;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class AppTest {
 @Autowired private IScalaMainClass smc;

 @Test public void testIt() {
  smc.doSomething();
 }
}
```

If you now add the scala dependencies to pom.xml and do "mvn test" you will receive

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
...
```

Comment: You need to show more code, how you call `doSomething()`, is it part of some trait (`IScalaMainClass`), how you configure `@Transactional` (XML?), can you show thread dump of *No transaction in progress* exception? How you build your application (failing to find a class during startup). I can assure you that Scala works perfectly with Spring.

Comment: I have now extended my original posted with a complete example so that you can reconstruct the problem step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be very careful when you look to Spring support for Transaction and other Aspect-oriented features.

- Autowiring an immutable field is not possible: autowiring is a pattern which sets up dependency after initialization, val is an immutable property which cannot be changed after initialization
- As you can read in the documentation, Spring AOP support is not based on bytecode weaving and it is purely implemented in Java: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html

This means that only beans which are created through Spring IoC could benefit of Spring AOP support.

If you look in the introduction of the chapter you can read:

> AOP is used in the Spring Framework to...
>
> ... provide declarative enterprise services, especially as a
>   replacement for EJB declarative services. The most important such
>   service is declarative transaction management.

So if your bean is not created through Spring, you will not have spring transaction support available.

Comment: You were right. I created a ScalaMainClassFacade in Java which is annotated with @Transactional and simply calls the autowired ScalaMainClass. But isn't there any way to use Scala alone???

Comment: Not with the way Spring AOP it is designed. The documentation explains it (but I agree that could be furtherly underlined): Spring AOP is not able to do that because it does not do byte-code injection and there is no special compilation process for aspects: at run-time, when the IoC container loads the context, it has some BeanFactoryPostProcessors who take care of applying your aspects. So, no IoC, no Aspects. You have to use AspectJ and not Spring AOP if you want AOP oriented programming to be available outside the IOC

Comment: I actually wanted to add that developing your own transaction management aspects to be used outside Spring is not trivial. What does the transactional annotation do is to tell Spring to use a platform transaction manager available in the app context to start and commit or rollback the transaction . If you want code that runs outside the container, where would you get the reference to the transaction manager?

Answer (score 1):

While I agree mostly on @Edmondo1984's answer, I think rainerh's code above has put all the beans in Spring context, hence it can work with Spring Transaction.

From the code above, I think you should change the Test as follow

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
public class AppTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
 @Autowired private IScalaMainClass smc;

 @Test public void testIt() {
  smc.doSomething();
 }
}
```

Don't forget to import `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`